# ¿Cómo guardar valor predeterminado en MySQL en "phpmyadmin"?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

tengo un formulario "signup" conectado a base de datos en "phpmyadmin" todo "funciona" correctamente el problema que tengo es que tengo un campo "type_role" en el cual pues tiene predeterminado "role_admin" al momento de suscribirse en la página web si guarda todo en la base de datos pero el campo antes mencionado lo deja vacio, ¿Cómo soluciono eso?
Hice unas pequeñas modifiaciones como agregar un campo con la misma funncionalidad y eso provoca que llene los campos pero los nuevo los vuelve a dejar vacios.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require 'conexion.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $insert = "INSERT into registro values 
    ('','$name','$lastname','$email','$password',now(),'')";
    $registro_insert = mysqli_query($conexion, $insert)
        or die ("No se logro registrar");

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Base de Datos]

Comment: Hola, como estas poniendo el id como Auto-increment y el campo "role_type" como predeterminado, no es necesario asignarles ese valor `''`, solo con esto basta: `$insert = "INSERT into registro values('$name','$lastname','$email','$password',now())";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Hay 2 errores principales en tu consulta

Error 1.- Le estas pasando como dato `''` a ID lo cual es incorrecto, basta con no agregarlo en tu sentencia, si lo tienes **auto incrementable** mysql lo hara por ti.

Error 2.- Del mismo modo pasa con tu campo `role_type` le estas pasando `''` de igual manera, no tienes por que pasarlo en tu sentencia mysql lo hara por ti por que ya tiene un valor predeterminado,

2.- Tu sentencia quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
$insert = "INSERT into registro (name, lastname, email, password, dateSignup) 
           VALUES 
            ('$name','$lastname','$email','$password',now())";

       $registro_insert = mysqli_query($conexion, $insert)
        or die ("No se logro registrar");
```

Comment: Lo hice como dices quitar las '' pero me marca error no se cumple el query INSERT

Comment: @Minor Tal vez no me explique bien, edite mi respuesta para que puedas ver como sera tu consulta, Recuerda que: **En la sentencia INSERT tienes que decirle la tabla donde insertaras, los campos en donde insertaras y los valores que tendran esos campos**

Comment: Si te explicaste bien, pero no funciona, por ahí lei que debes debes dejar los '' para que la base de datos los respete y los llene con el A_I y el predeterminado

Comment: @Minor Copia y pega el codigo que te actualice, deberia de funcionar.

Comment: perdon si funciona, error de dedo en el código, te comento que habia leido algo así pero bueno todos los días se aprende algo nuevo ¡Gracias!

Comment: Si, la habia marcado, que extraño la remarque ¡gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes de hacer es insertar solo los valores que necesitas aquí la sintaxis :

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Quedaría algo así como :

```
INSERT into registro (name, lastname, email, password, dateSignup) VALUES 
('$name','$lastname','$email','$password',now())
```

Comment: Pues tampoco funciona de esta manera, de hecho no tendrias porque poner el primer parentesis si en la base de datos ya lo tiene definido solo importa el orden del segundo parentesis

Comment: @Minor Creo que estas algo confundido, en la sentencia INSERT tienes que decirle la tabla donde insertaras los campos en donde insertaras y los valores que tendran esos campos

Comment: Ah si sabia eso pero tengo entendido que no aplica en formularios, aplica pero en otras maneras

Comment: Implica en cualquier caso, te recomiendo leer esto para saber mas al respecto @Minor [php_mysql_insert W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: ¡Gracias, encontre el error!